# How to find equation for this sequence of numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I have a sequence of numbers 0, 1, 5, 19, ....
This is the pseudocode to generate the sequence

$c = 0$

for $i=0, 1, 2, ...:$

$    c = 3c + 2^i$

Does anyone know how I would write an equation $f(i)$ that would generate this same sequence?

Thanks

Comment: Solve the linear recurrence $a_{n+1}=3a_n+2^n$

Comment: How do I solve the linear recurrence?

Comment: I found it, I put `g(0)=0, g(n+1)=3*g(n)+2^n` on wolfram alpha, and it gave me $f(i)=3^i-2^i$.

Comment: I figured out the formula with the help of PARI/GP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generating function is $$f(n)=3^n-2^n$$

Proof by induction : The base case $n=0$ is clear.

Now, we have $$3^{n+1}-2^{n+1}=3\cdot(3^n-2^n)+3\cdot 2^n-2^{n+1}=3\cdot(3^n-2^n)+2^n$$

So, we have $f(n+1)=3f(n)+2^n$, completing the proof.